# Converting CSV File to Complex XML Array via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of converting CSV data to XML format and then this data will be loaded to a multipart form to send via API request. Currently I am having a hard time getting the correct layout for My Data.

This is my current dataset:

```
"order_num","delivery_type","account_num","customer_code","customer_location","customer_name","customer_address","customer_city","customer_state","customer_zip","phone1","delivery_date","cod","sku","quantity","description","line_taxes","amount","category_name","open","close","time_window_open","time_window_close","size_1","size_2","size_3","category_1_size_1","category_1_size_2","category_1_size_3","category_2_size_1","category_2_size_2","category_2_size_3","category_3_size_1","category_3_size_2","category_3_size_3","comment_1","comment_2","comment_3","latitude","longitude",       
"3238204","Delivery","SOUTH","     10309"," ","MADISON BISTRO","135 N. COURT STREET","WAMPSVILLE","NY","13163","3152800228","07/09/19"," ","     13075","1","BACON E.Z. PAN EXTRA SMOKE 10-12/LB"," ","81.57","Frozen","900","2000","900","1300",".84","21.00","1.00"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","DRIVER BRING CURB RAMP"," "," ","43.0805","-75.7077",       
"3238204","Delivery","SOUTH","     10309"," ","MADISON BISTRO","135 N. COURT STREET","WAMPSVILLE","NY","13163","3152800228","07/09/19"," ","     22027","1","CORNED BEEF ROUND COOKED"," ","43.73","Refer","900","2000","900","1300",".35","12.82","1.00"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","DRIVER BRING CURB RAMP"," "," ","43.0805","-75.7077",       
"3238204","Delivery","SOUTH","     10309"," ","MADISON BISTRO","135 N. COURT STREET","WAMPSVILLE","NY","13163","3152800228","07/09/19"," ","     25052","1","CHEESE CHEDDAR SHARP WHITE BLOCK"," ","32.70","Refer","900","2000","900","1300",".23","10.22","1.00"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","DRIVER BRING CURB RAMP"," "," ","43.0805","-75.7077",       
"3238217","Delivery","SOUTH","     13093"," ","OLD SCHOOL BAR AND GRILL","600 CULVER AVE SUITE 3","UTICA","NY","13501","3157971980","07/09/19"," ","     12123","4","BEEF BUTT TENDERS FROZEN"," ","220.91","Frozen","830","2100","900","1300","3.44","141.64","4.00"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","43.0902","-75.1987",       
"3238217","Delivery","SOUTH","     13093"," ","OLD SCHOOL BAR AND GRILL","600 CULVER AVE SUITE 3","UTICA","NY","13501","3157971980","07/09/19"," ","     88184","1","PEPPERS LONG HOT"," ","58.90","Refer","830","2100","900","1300","1.39","21.75","1.00"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","43.0902","-75.1987",       
"3238217","Delivery","SOUTH","     13093"," ","OLD SCHOOL BAR AND GRILL","600 CULVER AVE SUITE 3","UTICA","NY","13501","3157971980","07/09/19"," ","     88137","10","LETTUCE ROMAINE CHOPPED"," ","22.81","Refer","830","2100","900","1300","10.32","130.00","10.00"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","43.0902","-75.1987",
```

Below is the PowerShell Code i am currently using:

```
$OrderFile = "C:\users\mvincenty\desktop\Order Data2.csv"
$OrderData = Import-Csv -path $OrderFile
$OutputXML = "C:\users\mvincenty\desktop\orders.xml"

$TemplateCust = @'
<service_orders>
  <service_order>
    <account_name>$($item.customer_name)</account_name>
    <order_number>$($item.order_num)</order_number>
    <delivery_type>$($item.delivery_type)</delivery_type>
    <customer_code>$($item.customer_code)</customer_code>
    <delivery_date>$($item.delivery_date)</delivery_date>
    <cod>$($item.cod)</cod>
    <note></note>
    <customer>
      <number>$($item.customer_code)</number>
      <delivery_type>$($item.delivery_type)</delivery_type>
      <customer_name>$($item.customer_name)</customer_name>
      <address1>$($item.customer_address)</address1>
      <city>$($item.customer_city)</city>
      <state>$($item.customer_state)</state>
      <zip>$($item.customer_zip)</zip>
      <phone1>$($item.phone1)</phone1>
      <open_time>$($item.open)</open_time>
      <close_time>$($item.close)</close_time>
      <window_start_time_1>$($item.time_Window_open)</window_start_time_1>
      <window_end_time_1>$($item.time_Window_close)</window_end_time_1>
      <latitude>$($item.latitude)</latitude>
      <longitude>$($item.longitude)</longitude>
      <category_1_size_1>$($item.category_1_size_1)</category_1_size_1>
      <category_1_size_2>$($item.category_1_size_2)</category_1_size_2>
      <category_1_size_3>$($item.category_1_size_3)</category_1_size_3>
      <category_2_size_1>$($item.category_2_size_1)</category_2_size_1>
      <category_2_size_2>$($item.category_2_size_2)</category_2_size_2>
      <category_2_size_3>$($item.category_2_size_3)</category_2_size_3>
      <category_3_size_1>$($item.category_3_size_1)</category_3_size_1>
      <category_3_size_2>$($item.category_3_size_2)</category_3_size_2>
      <category_3_size_3>$($item.category_3_size_3)</category_3_size_3>
    </customer>
    <line_items>
    $($items -join "`n")
    </line_items>
  </service_order>
</service_orders>
'@

$TemplateItems = @'
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>$($item.sku)</serial_number>
        <quantity>$($item.quantity)</quantity>
        <amount>$($item.amount)</amount>
        <description>$($item.description)</description>
        <line_taxes>$($item.line_taxes)</line_taxes>
        <category_name>$($item.category_name)</category_name>
        <size_1>$($item.size_1)</size_1>
        <size_2>$($item.size_2)</size_2>
        <size_3>$($item.size_3)</size_3>
    </line_item>
'@


$xml = $OrderData | Group-Object order_num -ov grp| ForEach-Object {
    $items = foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
        $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateItems)
        }
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateCust)
}

$xml |Out-File $OutputXML
```

This is the output i am currently getting:

```
<service_orders>
  <service_order>
    <account_name>MADISON BISTRO</account_name>
    <order_number>3238204</order_number>
    <delivery_type>Delivery</delivery_type>
    <customer_code>     10309</customer_code>
    <delivery_date>07/09/19</delivery_date>
    <cod> </cod>
    <note></note>
    <customer>
      <number>     10309</number>
      <delivery_type>Delivery</delivery_type>
      <customer_name>MADISON BISTRO</customer_name>
      <address1>135 N. COURT STREET</address1>
      <city>WAMPSVILLE</city>
      <state>NY</state>
      <zip>13163</zip>
      <phone1>3152800228</phone1>
      <open_time>900</open_time>
      <close_time>2000</close_time>
      <window_start_time_1>900</window_start_time_1>
      <window_end_time_1>1300</window_end_time_1>
      <latitude>43.0805</latitude>
      <longitude>-75.7077</longitude>
      <category_1_size_1> </category_1_size_1>
      <category_1_size_2> </category_1_size_2>
      <category_1_size_3> </category_1_size_3>
      <category_2_size_1> </category_2_size_1>
      <category_2_size_2> </category_2_size_2>
      <category_2_size_3> </category_2_size_3>
      <category_3_size_1> </category_3_size_1>
      <category_3_size_2> </category_3_size_2>
      <category_3_size_3> </category_3_size_3>
    </customer>
    <line_items>
        <line_item>
        <serial_number>     13075</serial_number>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>81.57</amount>
        <description>BACON E.Z. PAN EXTRA SMOKE 10-12/LB</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Frozen</category_name>
        <size_1>.84</size_1>
        <size_2>21.00</size_2>
        <size_3>1.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>     22027</serial_number>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>43.73</amount>
        <description>CORNED BEEF ROUND COOKED</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Refer</category_name>
        <size_1>.35</size_1>
        <size_2>12.82</size_2>
        <size_3>1.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>     25052</serial_number>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>32.70</amount>
        <description>CHEESE CHEDDAR SHARP WHITE BLOCK</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Refer</category_name>
        <size_1>.23</size_1>
        <size_2>10.22</size_2>
        <size_3>1.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    </line_items>
  </service_order>
</service_orders>
<service_orders>
  <service_order>
    <account_name>OLD SCHOOL BAR AND GRILL</account_name>
    <order_number>3238217</order_number>
    <delivery_type>Delivery</delivery_type>
    <customer_code>     13093</customer_code>
    <delivery_date>07/09/19</delivery_date>
    <cod> </cod>
    <note></note>
    <customer>
      <number>     13093</number>
      <delivery_type>Delivery</delivery_type>
      <customer_name>OLD SCHOOL BAR AND GRILL</customer_name>
      <address1>600 CULVER AVE SUITE 3</address1>
      <city>UTICA</city>
      <state>NY</state>
      <zip>13501</zip>
      <phone1>3157971980</phone1>
      <open_time>830</open_time>
      <close_time>2100</close_time>
      <window_start_time_1>900</window_start_time_1>
      <window_end_time_1>1300</window_end_time_1>
      <latitude>43.0902</latitude>
      <longitude>-75.1987</longitude>
      <category_1_size_1> </category_1_size_1>
      <category_1_size_2> </category_1_size_2>
      <category_1_size_3> </category_1_size_3>
      <category_2_size_1> </category_2_size_1>
      <category_2_size_2> </category_2_size_2>
      <category_2_size_3> </category_2_size_3>
      <category_3_size_1> </category_3_size_1>
      <category_3_size_2> </category_3_size_2>
      <category_3_size_3> </category_3_size_3>
    </customer>
    <line_items>
        <line_item>
        <serial_number>     12123</serial_number>
        <quantity>4</quantity>
        <amount>220.91</amount>
        <description>BEEF BUTT TENDERS FROZEN</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Frozen</category_name>
        <size_1>3.44</size_1>
        <size_2>141.64</size_2>
        <size_3>4.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>     88184</serial_number>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>58.90</amount>
        <description>PEPPERS LONG HOT</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Refer</category_name>
        <size_1>1.39</size_1>
        <size_2>21.75</size_2>
        <size_3>1.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>     88137</serial_number>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
        <amount>22.81</amount>
        <description>LETTUCE ROMAINE CHOPPED</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Refer</category_name>
        <size_1>10.32</size_1>
        <size_2>130.00</size_2>
        <size_3>10.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    </line_items>
  </service_order>
</service_orders>
```

But the output that I am looking for is:
All of the service_orders combined under the services_orders

```
<service_orders>
  <service_order>
    <account_name>MADISON BISTRO</account_name>
    <order_number>3238204</order_number>
    <delivery_type>Delivery</delivery_type>
    <customer_code>     10309</customer_code>
    <delivery_date>07/09/19</delivery_date>
    <cod> </cod>
    <note></note>
    <customer>
      <number>     10309</number>
      <delivery_type>Delivery</delivery_type>
      <customer_name>MADISON BISTRO</customer_name>
      <address1>135 N. COURT STREET</address1>
      <city>WAMPSVILLE</city>
      <state>NY</state>
      <zip>13163</zip>
      <phone1>3152800228</phone1>
      <open_time>900</open_time>
      <close_time>2000</close_time>
      <window_start_time_1>900</window_start_time_1>
      <window_end_time_1>1300</window_end_time_1>
      <latitude>43.0805</latitude>
      <longitude>-75.7077</longitude>
      <category_1_size_1> </category_1_size_1>
      <category_1_size_2> </category_1_size_2>
      <category_1_size_3> </category_1_size_3>
      <category_2_size_1> </category_2_size_1>
      <category_2_size_2> </category_2_size_2>
      <category_2_size_3> </category_2_size_3>
      <category_3_size_1> </category_3_size_1>
      <category_3_size_2> </category_3_size_2>
      <category_3_size_3> </category_3_size_3>
    </customer>
    <line_items>
        <line_item>
        <serial_number>     13075</serial_number>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>81.57</amount>
        <description>BACON E.Z. PAN EXTRA SMOKE 10-12/LB</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Frozen</category_name>
        <size_1>.84</size_1>
        <size_2>21.00</size_2>
        <size_3>1.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>     22027</serial_number>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>43.73</amount>
        <description>CORNED BEEF ROUND COOKED</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Refer</category_name>
        <size_1>.35</size_1>
        <size_2>12.82</size_2>
        <size_3>1.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>     25052</serial_number>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>32.70</amount>
        <description>CHEESE CHEDDAR SHARP WHITE BLOCK</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Refer</category_name>
        <size_1>.23</size_1>
        <size_2>10.22</size_2>
        <size_3>1.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    </line_items>
  </service_order>
  <service_order>
    <account_name>OLD SCHOOL BAR AND GRILL</account_name>
    <order_number>3238217</order_number>
    <delivery_type>Delivery</delivery_type>
    <customer_code>     13093</customer_code>
    <delivery_date>07/09/19</delivery_date>
    <cod> </cod>
    <note></note>
    <customer>
      <number>     13093</number>
      <delivery_type>Delivery</delivery_type>
      <customer_name>OLD SCHOOL BAR AND GRILL</customer_name>
      <address1>600 CULVER AVE SUITE 3</address1>
      <city>UTICA</city>
      <state>NY</state>
      <zip>13501</zip>
      <phone1>3157971980</phone1>
      <open_time>830</open_time>
      <close_time>2100</close_time>
      <window_start_time_1>900</window_start_time_1>
      <window_end_time_1>1300</window_end_time_1>
      <latitude>43.0902</latitude>
      <longitude>-75.1987</longitude>
      <category_1_size_1> </category_1_size_1>
      <category_1_size_2> </category_1_size_2>
      <category_1_size_3> </category_1_size_3>
      <category_2_size_1> </category_2_size_1>
      <category_2_size_2> </category_2_size_2>
      <category_2_size_3> </category_2_size_3>
      <category_3_size_1> </category_3_size_1>
      <category_3_size_2> </category_3_size_2>
      <category_3_size_3> </category_3_size_3>
    </customer>
    <line_items>
        <line_item>
        <serial_number>     12123</serial_number>
        <quantity>4</quantity>
        <amount>220.91</amount>
        <description>BEEF BUTT TENDERS FROZEN</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Frozen</category_name>
        <size_1>3.44</size_1>
        <size_2>141.64</size_2>
        <size_3>4.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>     88184</serial_number>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>58.90</amount>
        <description>PEPPERS LONG HOT</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Refer</category_name>
        <size_1>1.39</size_1>
        <size_2>21.75</size_2>
        <size_3>1.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>     88137</serial_number>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
        <amount>22.81</amount>
        <description>LETTUCE ROMAINE CHOPPED</description>
        <line_taxes> </line_taxes>
        <category_name>Refer</category_name>
        <size_1>10.32</size_1>
        <size_2>130.00</size_2>
        <size_3>10.00</size_3>
    </line_item>
    </line_items>
  </service_order>
</service_orders>
```

Comment: Why not remove the <service_orders> tag from the template, then just add the opening tag to the variable before you process templates, and then append the closing tag after the loop completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we continue to follow your template format, then you could add another template/variable to deal with the outer tags.

```
$OrderFile = "C:\users\mvincenty\desktop\Order Data2.csv"
$OrderData = Import-Csv -path $OrderFile
$OutputXML = "C:\users\mvincenty\desktop\orders.xml"

$TemplateOuter = @'
<service_orders>
$($xml -join "`r`n")
</service_orders>
'@

$TemplateCust = @'
  <service_order>
    <account_name>$($item.customer_name)</account_name>
    <order_number>$($item.order_num)</order_number>
    <delivery_type>$($item.delivery_type)</delivery_type>
    <customer_code>$($item.customer_code)</customer_code>
    <delivery_date>$($item.delivery_date)</delivery_date>
    <cod>$($item.cod)</cod>
    <note></note>
    <customer>
      <number>$($item.customer_code)</number>
      <delivery_type>$($item.delivery_type)</delivery_type>
      <customer_name>$($item.customer_name)</customer_name>
      <address1>$($item.customer_address)</address1>
      <city>$($item.customer_city)</city>
      <state>$($item.customer_state)</state>
      <zip>$($item.customer_zip)</zip>
      <phone1>$($item.phone1)</phone1>
      <open_time>$($item.open)</open_time>
      <close_time>$($item.close)</close_time>
      <window_start_time_1>$($item.time_Window_open)</window_start_time_1>
      <window_end_time_1>$($item.time_Window_close)</window_end_time_1>
      <latitude>$($item.latitude)</latitude>
      <longitude>$($item.longitude)</longitude>
      <category_1_size_1>$($item.category_1_size_1)</category_1_size_1>
      <category_1_size_2>$($item.category_1_size_2)</category_1_size_2>
      <category_1_size_3>$($item.category_1_size_3)</category_1_size_3>
      <category_2_size_1>$($item.category_2_size_1)</category_2_size_1>
      <category_2_size_2>$($item.category_2_size_2)</category_2_size_2>
      <category_2_size_3>$($item.category_2_size_3)</category_2_size_3>
      <category_3_size_1>$($item.category_3_size_1)</category_3_size_1>
      <category_3_size_2>$($item.category_3_size_2)</category_3_size_2>
      <category_3_size_3>$($item.category_3_size_3)</category_3_size_3>
    </customer>
    <line_items>
    $($items -join "`n")
    </line_items>
  </service_order>
'@

$TemplateItems = @'
    <line_item>
        <serial_number>$($item.sku)</serial_number>
        <quantity>$($item.quantity)</quantity>
        <amount>$($item.amount)</amount>
        <description>$($item.description)</description>
        <line_taxes>$($item.line_taxes)</line_taxes>
        <category_name>$($item.category_name)</category_name>
        <size_1>$($item.size_1)</size_1>
        <size_2>$($item.size_2)</size_2>
        <size_3>$($item.size_3)</size_3>
    </line_item>
'@


$xml = $OrderData | Group-Object order_num -ov grp| ForEach-Object {
    $items = foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
        $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateItems)
        }
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateCust)
}

$xml = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateOuter)
$xml | Out-File $OutputXML
```

**Notable Changes From Original Code:**

I added `$TemplateOuter` and removed the `<service_orders>` tagging from `$TemplateCust`.

**Explanation:**

`$TemplateOuter` contains the `<service_orders>` outer tags. Between the opening the closing tags is the `$xml` output excluding those outer tags. I had to use the `$()` sub-expression operator because the here-string (`@''@`) does not expand variables. The reason for the `-join` operator is that when you stringify an array, which is what `$xml` is, it will join each array element with a single space. The `-join` in the code creates a CRLF between the elements instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The changes to the code above seem to work well. There is an alternative method i found that i will post as well as i have not decided which is the best route as my "unclean" method seems to perform faster.

Comment: I will be creating a second post as i am having an issue with how the data is being expanded with the grouping. For some reason some of the <service_orders> are being added inside other <service_orders>. I have validated the data and there is no errors and the group-object seems to recognize that there is 244 objects so I am what could be causing it and i am not familiar with the group-object to really understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This method seems to work as well.

first i created a file that contains the first  tag and the I modified the code as follows

```
$xml = $OrderData | Group-Object order_num -ov grp| ForEach-Object {
    $items = foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
        $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateItems)
        }
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($TemplateCust) | Add-Content -Path $TemplateFile
    }
Add-Content -Path $TemplateFile -Value '</service_orders>'
```

I am sure there are better ways but both of these have the same outcome.